# How can I create CSV files with a secure/unique separation of fields?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I create a CSV file:

```
$newFileName = "myfile.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($newFileName,"w"); 

foreach ($data as $line){
   fputcsv($fileHandle, array($line['id'], $line['name'],$line['path']));
}

fclose($fileHandle); 
   if (!empty($fileHandle)) {
   echo "CSV was successfully created";
} else {
echo "Error creating CSV";
}
```

and store it into the mySQL database:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv'
        INTO TABLE test
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (id,name,path)";

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpassword","dbname");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 };

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {
    $message = "The data was successfully added!";
 } else {
    $message = "The user update failed: ";
    $message .= mysqli_error($con); 
 };

 echo $message;
 mysqli_close($con);
```

To me the separation with "comma" doesn't seem to be very secure. I am afraid, if in the path for example, there will be a "comma" somewhere the data will be stored incorrect into the database. Can you suggest me a unique or more secure separation method of fields for the cvs file?

Comment: Have you tried to put some commas in the fields?

Comment: Start by understanding how a CSV file is supposed to handle data where the separator exists within that data - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) - csv has a documented approach to deal with this issue, which is really a non-issue, because the developers of MySQL actually thought of the possible problem before you did

Comment: @sec_aw Oh actually I didn't know that. So there is no problem, where I thought there will be a problem :D

Comment: Updated comment: This is 'secure', as you have the option OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY set. This means that string data types will be enclosed in quotation marks, so that commas will not be interpreted as field separators.

Comment: And before you ask the next logical question; the enclosed by character is escaped when it appears in the data that is being enclosed

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you very much for your help. Maybe you can answer me another short question. I always get the error "The user update failed:" although everything was successfully added to the database.

Comment: Because `LOAD DATA INFILE` doesn't directly affect any rows, it's an indirect change.... quoting from the PHP docs: `Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.`.... LOAD DATA INFILE isn't any of the listed query statements

Comment: @Mark Baker: Ok, I understand, thank you so much! So I have to make the success check in a different way for LOAD DATA INFILE, I will research about it. Have a very nice day

Comment: I found it. I have to change  `if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {` to `if ($result) {`